# Use LOAD DATA INFILE to load two CSV files into same rows

Tags: mysql, csv, load-data-infile

I have two CSV files, each containing different columns that I want to merge into one database. I set up a database with all the columns from both files, but when I use load data infile to import both files instead of merging (IE data file 1 fills columns 1-6, data file 2 fills 7-10) I get a database with twice as many rows (one row for each record in each CSV) and NULLS filling in the data not represented in the source CSV.

I know I can fix this by merging the CSVs somehow, importing with overwrite enabled, or combining the data in the database - what's the most efficient way for me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is with a script.  CSV import scripts are usually written in a scripting language such as python, ruby, or php.

You just need the importer for the second CSV to perform updates on the records created in the first CSV, so the script will really only be 5-10 lines.  If you provide a sample record from each CSV, I'd be happy to write one for you.

**Edit:**  Here's a python script to combine the files, adding a semicolon between lines from file1 and lines from file2.  This essentially does what Linux's `paste` command would do.

```
lines1 = open('file1.txt').readlines()
lines2 = open('file2.txt').readlines()
outfile = open('outfile.txt', 'w')

if len(lines1) != len(lines2):
    raise Exception("Files need to be the same length, but file1 is %s lines long and file2 is %s lines long" % (len(lines1), len(lines2)));

for i in range(len(lines1)):
    combined = lines1[i].strip() + ";" + lines2[i].strip() + "\n"
    outfile.write(combined)
```

You can run it by saving it as `combine.py` and typing `python combine.py`.  The folder you place it in should contain `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, and `outfile.txt`.

Comment: Here's the dataset for each csv: #1 - "Address";"State";"ZIP Code", #2 - "Office";"Contact";"ContactTitle";"Phone"

Comment: on which field should they be merged?  or do they each contain an ID field?

Comment: There are 180 records in each of them, they're lined up perfectly record-to-record

Comment: Okay.  Are the DB column names identical to `"Address";"State";"ZIP Code", #2 - "Office";"Contact";"ContactTitle";"Phone"`?

Comment: DB columns are named slightly different, but I can edit them as necessary.

Comment: I made a script to combine the files, since that's easier :)

Answer (score 1):

Combine two CSV into one.

If you are in linux platform, use the `paste` command to join two or more files.

```
PASTE(1)

NAME
       paste - merge lines of files

SYNOPSIS
       paste [OPTION]... [FILE]...

DESCRIPTION
       Write lines consisting of the sequentially corresponding lines from 
       each FILE, separated by TABs, to standard output.  
       With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.

       Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.

       -d, --delimiters=LIST
              reuse characters from LIST instead of TABs

       -s, --serial
              paste one file at a time instead of in parallel

       --help display this help and exit

       --version
              output version information and exit
```

such as

```
paste file1.csv file2.csv > file3.csv
```

Comment: I'm on windows, so I can't use this. Is there any comparable function/utility for windows?

Comment: The problem is that he doesn't need them stacked up vertically, but joined horizontally based on the id.

Comment: do you have cygwin installed?

Comment: @dorkitude - you can use sort on any particular field in linux

Answer (score 0):

I would look at Perl and the [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV) module.  One issue you'll need to think about is whether the data is in the same order in the two files.